# How to solve error of "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (likes) on node type (Post)" in facebook graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am getting the below error during the fetching the Facebook user feed using the Facebook graph API.

> (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (likes) on node type (Post)

Screenshot shot of error.

[image]

My current API call is below

> [https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?fields=from,created_time,likes.summary(true),comments.limit(0).summary(true),full_picture,picture,attachments{unshimmed_url,title,media_type,media{source},description},message,story,shares&limit=10&access_token=LONG_LIVE_TOKEN](https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?fields=from,created_time,likes.summary(true),comments.limit(0).summary(true),full_picture,picture,attachments%7Bunshimmed_url,title,media_type,media%7Bsource%7D,description%7D,message,story,shares&limit=10&access_token=LONG_LIVE_TOKEN)

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Facebook does not provide feed data for the profile as per the new policy. Now, we have to create the profile page.

To create a profile type of page please check the below URL.
https://www.facebook.com/help/135275340210354

So now I have created the page for my profile and getting the feed from the profile page.